# why cell.tap not work properly in XCTest?

Tags: swift, xctest

I write an extension to select a cell from tableView. However, it works fine but in some case it not worked.

```
self.scrollToElement(element: element)
element.tap()
```

Note: that isHittable property is true while it's tapping and logs also printed as it's tapped.

Comment: Ram, could you share what `tap()` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what went wrong since your question is a bit unclear.

Yet I suppose some of your cells get overlapped by UITabBarView (or something like that) and you should swipe a little bit more.

Note that `isHittable` is not precise and its results may be a false positive and a false negative.